# How would you replace the Dynamixels on Turtlebot3 with DC motors?

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ros-kinetic, dynamixel-motor, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to replace the Dynamixels on Turtlebot3 with an Arduino, driver, and DC motors with encoders?  If so, how?

Has anyone gone through this process and knows which steps need to be taken or what code has to be changed?

I think I understand the basics of reading in from the motor and sending commands, but it seems like the Dynamixels do a lot more that I would need to replicate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288806/how-would-you-replace-the-dynamixels-on-turtlebot3-with-dc-motors?/) by [MarksMan0011](https://answers.ros.org/users/34666/marksman0011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Dynamixel is a high-performance actuator with a fully integrated DC Motor + Reduction Gearhead + Controller + Driver + Sensors(like encoder) + Network, all in one servo module actuator. So you can replace it with a DC motor, but you have to program the motor, driver, encoder and associated control routines.

If you have a motor, driver, and encoder, you can achieve your goal with the basic component of TurtleBot3, OpenCR. OpenCR is developed for ROS embedded systems to provide completely open-source hardware and software. Everything about the board; Schematics, PCB Gerber, BOM and the firmware source code for the TurtleBot3 are free to distribute under open-source licenses for users and the ROS community. OpenCR supports the Arduino IDE, so you can use a variety of Arduino libraries. Please see documents below for more information.
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/controller/opencr10/

---

Originally posted by [Pyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/632/pyo/) with karma: 358 on 2018-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0